# Flexboxs children overflows parents

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have seen a few questions like mine, but none of them seemed to be sucessfully answered. My problem might be simple, but I dont get my mistake.

**I use several flexboxes in each other. When i change the browsers size it should resize the same way. But at a point the childrens are overflowing the parent flexbox - Ugly**

Because I've not found my mistake, i started a new HTML doc - I still have the mistake.
The "gamebox"s children dont do as I want them to.

**Here's a fiddle: [Live-Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qgtn92xp/)**

**Thank you for your help**
 - RoetzerBub

```css
html , body, main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
header, footer{
    display: flex;
    min-width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
header{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: #cc0000;
    color: white;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

main{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

footer{
    background-color: #444444;
    color: white;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
/*as*/
.gamebox{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-width: 30%;
    max-width: 45%;
    border: 2px solid #b30000;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.gb_left, .gb_center, .gb_right{
    margin: 2%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.gb_left{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.gb_right{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    
}

.gb_center{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexstyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>HEADER</header>
        <main>
            
            <div class="gamebox">
                <div class="gb_left">
                    FLAG
                    TEAM-A
                </div>
                <div class="gb_center">
                    type<br/>
                    SCORE<br/>
                    date
                </div>
                <div class="gb_right">
                    TEAM-B
                    FLAG  
                </div>
              
            </div>
        
        </main>
        <footer>FOOTER</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense here to define the children as flex containers again - there are no elements in them (divs or spans), only text (i.e. nothing that could function as a flex item).

In the following fiddle I removed all this and used the following CSS settings:

```
 .gamebox{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-width: 30%;
    max-width: 45%;
    border: 2px solid #b30000;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.gb_left, .gb_center, .gb_right{
    margin: 2%;
    background-color: yellow;
    min-width: 29%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

The very last one makes sure that when a word is longer than the width of its container, it's broken.

Here is the fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o6wxy5z7/

Comment: Thank you :) - Helped me

Comment: @RoetzerBub this is the way to go as far I can see this is the  best answer as I said w3c specification says only solution is to set min-width

Answer (score 1):

To prevent elements from overflowing their containers you need to allow them to shrink as well as grow, for example:

`.gb_left{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
}`

can be changed to:

`.gb_left{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}`

using the shorthand to assign `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`.

Comment: Thank you Steve :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width:400px) {
  .gamebox {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Which prevents overflow and keeping in touch with responsive design element

Comment: Yes youre right, its working but i wanted the gamebox to be inline even if youre on a mobile device.

Comment: By default, flex items won’t shrink below their minimum content size (the length of the longest word or fixed-size element). To change this, set the min-width or min-height property. (See §4.5 Implied Minimum Size of Flex Items.) this is what w3c specification says

Answer (score 0):

First off, there are four styles you are using for the flex's children that don't belong to them.

Remove these from the flex children (.gb-left, .gb-center, and .gb-right.):

- display
- justify-content
- align-items
- flex-direction

Here is a good article on what should be assigned to who: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**Now for your problem with the children not shrinking** past a certain point -- the text wraps as much as it can and then when the text is as small as it can be it holds the width of the box open.

There is an easy way around this, although it will mean cutting off the text.

**Just assign overflow: hidden; to the children.**

```
.gb_left, .gb_center, .gb_right {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 2%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```